# Jquery Session not work with firefox

Tags: jquery, session, firefox

I have a problem with jquery.session.js and firefox.

I use this code for Login:

```
            if ($.session.get("logged") == 0 || $.session.get("logged") == "undefined") {
            $.session.set("logged", 2);
                 //self.location = self.location;
                location.reload(true);
        }
```

In Chrome and in IE the session work fine, but in Firefox the session (I think) is read too slowly and the browser continuously reloading.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have value of "2" on the logged key on IE and Chrome and undefined on Firefox.

In the if statement you are check if the value of the session "logged" is 2 or undefined string. To check if variable is undefined you need to check typeof that variable equals undefined.

Can you try updating the code to check typeof $.session.get("logged").

```
$(function() {

    if ($.session.get("logged") == 0 || typeof $.session.get("logged") === "undefined") {

        $.session.set("logged", 2);
        location.reload(true);

    }

});
```